# Twisted adbapi: number affected rows and last insert id

Tags: sql, twisted

ConnectionPool.runQuery returns Transaction.fetchall(). How do I get number of affected rows or last insert id?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the property `Transaction.lastrowid`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953784/twisted-adbapi-runinteraction-last-insert-id) of use [Transaction](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.enterprise.adbapi.Transaction.html) to get the last insert id, please refer the question demo code.

You will always get 0 if you do like this in two separate query:

self.dbpool.runQuery('insert into table_x (%s, %s)', ('str1', 'str2'))
self.dbpool.runQuery('select LAST_INSERT_ID()')