# Get last row id from runQuery

Tags: python, twisted, pymysql

I am inserting with twisted runQuery into mysql. How to i get the last inserted row id from the transaction? Actually i do another sql query after insert, but this isnt really elegant.

according to ([Twisted adbapi: number affected rows and last insert id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951267/twisted-adbapi-number-affected-rows-and-last-insert-id)), there should be a lastrowid property but this seems not to be true.

```
@inlineCallbacks
def get_or_create_node_id(self, node_name):
    try:
        record_exists = yield self.db.runQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM nodes WHERE name = %s", (node_name))
    except ConnectionError:
        log.error("db interaction failed due to connection error")
    if record_exists[0]['COUNT(*)'] == 0:
        log.info("creating new nodes entry {node_name}", node_name=node_name)
        try:
            call_insert = yield self.db.runQuery("INSERT INTO nodes (name) VALUES (%s)", (node_name))
            node_id = yield self.db.runQuery("SELECT id FROM nodes WHERE name = %s", (node_name))
            returnValue(int(node_id[0]['id']))
        except ConnectionError:
            log.error("db interaction failed due to connection error")
    else:
        try:
            node_id = yield self.db.runQuery("SELECT id FROM nodes WHERE name = %s", (node_name))
            returnValue(int(node_id[0]['id']))
        except ConnectionError:
            log.error("db interaction failed due to connection error")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.  Details are described in [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

> With no argument, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns a `BIGINT UNSIGNED` (64-bit) value representing the first automatically generated value successfully inserted for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column as a result of the most recently executed `INSER`T statement. The value of `LAST_INSERT_ID(`) remains unchanged if no rows are successfully inserted.

*Edit*: you should also be able to use [`runInteraction()`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.enterprise.adbapi.ConnectionPool.html#runInteraction) and access `lastRowId()`:

```
node_id = yield self.db.runInteraction(get_node_id, node_name)
...


def get_node_id(cursor, name):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO nodes (name) VALUES (%s)", name)
    return cursor.lastRowId()
```